# partial matching of an entire word using elasticsearch - matching the end or middle part

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

i've read through so much of the documentation, but now getting a bit confused about how to match part of a word in a search. i understand there are many techniques, but most talk about matching the first part of a word. such as 'quick' can match 'quick brown fox'.

well, what if i have the word 'endgame' i'm looking for but the input query is 'game'? i've tried using the standard, keyword, whitespace, etc, tokenizers but i'm not getting it.

i'm sure i'm missing something simple.

**update**

i was able to implement this with the help of john. here's the implementation using Nest...

```
var ngramTokenFilter = new NgramTokenFilter
{
    MinGram = 2,
    MaxGram = 3
};

var nGramTokenizer = new NGramTokenizer
{
    MinGram = 2, MaxGram = 3, TokenChars = new List<string>{"letter", "digit"}
};

var nGramAnalyzer = new CustomAnalyzer
{
    Tokenizer = "nGramTokenizer",
    Filter = new[] { "ngram", "standard", "lowercase" }
};


client.CreateIndex("myindex", i =>
{
    i
        .Analysis(a => a.Analyzers(an => an             
            .Add("ngramAnalyer", nGramAnalyzer)
            )
            .Tokenizers(tkn => tkn
                .Add("nGramTokenizer", nGramTokenizer)
            )
            .TokenFilters(x => x
                .Add("ngram", ngramTokenFilter)
                )
            )
            ...
```

and my poco, i'm actually creating a multifield, one not analyzed, and one with my ngram tokenizer analyzer:

```
pm.Properties(props => props
    .MultiField(mf => mf
        .Name("myfield")
        .Fields(f => f
            .String(s => s.Name("myfield").Analyzer("ngramAnalyer"))
            .String(s => s.Name("raw").Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try an ngram tokenizer: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

The example below is fairly extreme (it creates 2 and 3 letter tokens) but should give you an idea of how it works:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test' -d '
    {
        "settings" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "my_ngram_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "my_ngram_tokenizer"
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer" : {
                    "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                        "type" : "nGram",
                        "min_gram" : "2",
                        "max_gram" : "3",
                        "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }'

curl 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?pretty=1&analyzer=my_ngram_analyzer' -d 'FC Schalke 04' 
Result: FC, Sc, Sch, ch, cha, ha, hal, al, alk, lk, lke, ke, 04
```

This will allow you to break up your tokens into smaller tokens of a configurable size and search on them. You'll want to play with min_gram and max_gram for your use case.

This can have some memory impact but tends to be a lot faster than a wildcard search that has trailing or leading wildcards (or both). http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: thanks. i did see that in the documentation, but wasn't sure how to implement it. would i set it as an analyzer on the field i'm using? how do they affect the index - meaning are they indexed lowercase, whitespace, etc?

Comment: Look at the code example, that curl -XPUT is setting it as an analyzer for the index. To set it for a specific field you will need to adjust your mapping: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-analyzer-field.html This does not impact whitespace tokenization or lowercase filters, you will need to do those (or not) separately.

Comment: thanks for your help. i've implemented it and it does now seem to work. i'll update my question with my implementation (uses Nest).

Comment: Did you get any luck with using wildcard?